# How to include php files from another subdomain

Tags: php, html

I am creating a login server for my website and I am trying to connect my php file to another subdomains of my website,any idea?
the coding I am using:

```
<?php include("http://login.exa.com/"); ?>
```

for example:
main url: http://exa.com
subdomain http://login.exa.com
and I want to connect the php file on main bomain to other subdomains how can I do it?

Comment: You can't access the source code of a PHP file through HTTP like that. If you could, it would be a _massive_ security issue. You need to make sure both sites are on the same server and then include the files you need through the file system instead. Something like: `include '/absolute/path/to/the/file.php';`

Comment: you want to include the result of the php file or include the php as server side and execute its code ? also are these 2 domains under the same server?

Comment: By doing an HTTP request to  the subdomain, the subdomain's webserver will interpret the PHP and return you the result. So, you cannot include the PHP code using HTTP. If the subdomain is on the same server, you can use a relative of absolute path to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to omit the `<?php` part (and implement some security before that). And then you can do the following:

```
eval(get_file_contents('http://example.com/functions.php'));
```

But I won't even start about all the possible security problems.

Comment: If the OP omits the `<?php` from the code they can't use it (without using `eval()`) on either site. **Just a warning**, this is a _very_ bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Including PHP from other domains isn't possible.
This is mainly because of a huge security risk that i would pose if anyone was able to do this, just imagine if anyone could just include your private code into their library. The perspective of php engine you are and outsider and shouldn't have access and without dropping safeguarding there really isn't a way around it.

The best alternate method i can think of would be to build a api that talks between the two subdomains and and can commune with login via a series of post requests. RESTFUL based apis might be a place to start.